# JSF 2.0 CDI + Spring 3.1 Integration, FacesContext is null at deployment time

Tags: java, spring, jsf

When I run my project, Spring invoke `PostConstruct` mehod of `JSF Action Bean` method at deployment time (during of spring bean creation, I think).

As I thought, there is no `FacesCOntext` at deployment time, I get `NullPointerException` at `PostConstruct` method.

```
import javax.inject.Named;  
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AddStudentActionBean implements Serializable {
    private Student student;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        student = (Student) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("Student");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destory() {

    }
}
```

How can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't let `Spring` to create a bean of `AddStudentActionBean` class. I mean, there is no meaning of doing it. `CDI` container will create and manage `AddStudentActionBean` bean when its needed.

Generally you will like to create `Service` or `DAO` beans in `Spring`'s context.

Comment: If so, I cannot `ViewScoped` of `omnifaces`.

Comment: You can still use `@ViewScoped` of `omnifaces` as this bean is managed by `CDI container` not `Spring`.

Comment: Without EJB, Spring, Can I use `@Name`?

Comment: Of course you can, @Named of `javax.inject.Named` is a CDI annotation. Nothing to do with Spring or EJB.

Comment: JSF said  cannot found `addStudentActionBean` action bean